# Qt/C++ - Set background of disabled button?

Tags: c++, qt

I have all my buttons disabled in a grid, but for some, I'd like to change the background color. I'm trying:

```
_fieldButtons[0][0]->setStyleSheet("color: blue; background-color: blue;");
```

Where

```
QVector<QVector<QPushButton*> > _fieldButtons;
```

However, these buttons are all disabled, and only the text color gets changed:

[image]

How can I change the background, but not the text? Thank you!

**UPDATE**
I figured it's not working because the buttons are flat. How can I change flat button colors?

Comment: 'color: blue' changes the color of the text, remove it from your code if you want to avoid it

Comment: @JLev I know and that's ok, the main thing is that the background doesn't change.

Comment: @G.M. That also doesn't change the button's color.

Comment: Removed my original comment as I seem to have misunderstood your question.  What property of the `QPushButton` do you want to change and in which state(s)?

Comment: @G.M. I have a flat, disabled button, and I want to change its background color. If I use non-flat buttons, this works, for flat buttons it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, but even with `setFlat(true)` the style sheet `"::disabled { background-color: blue; }"` appears to work just fine for me -- the enabled button looks as it normally does and the background changes to blue when the button is disabled (I'm using Qt 5.8 on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Add `border: none;` to your stylesheet.
2. Use `setAutoFillBackground(true)` in conjunction with `QPalette::Button`

   ```
   myButton->setFlat(true);
   myButton->setAutoFillBackground(true);
   QPalette pal = myButton->palette();
   pal.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor(Qt::blue));
   myButton->setPalette(pal);
   ```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#flat-prop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myButton->setPalette(QColor("#124e6b"));
```

simply change the `QColor` to suit your use.

Or in Qt Creator you can right-click on the widget and select `Change Style Sheet`, as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here you have two "**Pseudo-States**" in your control. For list of "**Pseudo-States**" refer below link.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states

The first "Pseudo-State" is -- **flat**

The second "Pseudo-State" is -- **disabled**

Here you have to club both the states to set the style using "setStyleSheet".

```
_fieldButtons[0][0]->setStyleSheet(":flat:disabled {background-color: blue; border: none;}");
```

look for ":hover:enabled" (two different "**Pseudo-States**" how documentation handled) in the below link to get better idea.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html

To understand, why you we have to give `border:none` for `QPushButton`, please look for below information in the first hyperlink in this answer.

"Warning: If you only set a background-color on a QPushButton, the background may not appear unless you set the border property to some value. This is because, by default, the QPushButton draws a native border which completely overlaps the background-color."